# byte array in HashMap of Strings

Tags: java, hashmap

I am retrieving a map of user date, which dataMap of type `HashMap<String, String>`, and it has this key value pair, String, and `byte[]` of size 6.

Has anybody seen this before or know what to do?

Comment: Show us some code. Looks like you're trying to use byte[] in place of a string.

Comment: Solved : Just type casted the HashMap it to a Map and retrieved the value as an object (typecasting the value again to byte[])..

Answer (score 2):

There is something very fishy about your code.

These statements imply that `MappedRecord` must implement `Map<String, String>`.

```
record = (MappedRecord) obj;
item = new HashMap<String, String>();
item.putAll(record);
```

But then you say that this is inserting an entry whose value type is `byte[]`.  This is possible, but it must mean that somewhere / somehow you have *previously* added that entry to your `MappedRecord` object.  And in order for that to happen, you must be either suppressing or ignoring "unchecked conversion" warnings.

(Note that the `putAll` code doesn't check that the entries that it is adding to `item` have the right key and value types.  It can't!  The code for `HashMap.putAll` doesn't know what the parameter types should be ... due to type erasure.  Rather, the `putAll` code assumes that the types of the actual keys and values are correct.  And they should be ... unless you have ignored / suppressed the warnings.)

Either way, we won't be able to properly diagnose this without seeing the code of the `MappedRecord` class, and the code that is creating the `MappedRecord` instance that has the bogus entry in it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the method is doing @SuppressWarnings("unchecked").. I was not sure why this was there earlier. This method is involved in the process of which I am retrieving my data..So looks like someone before me purposefully did this.. so what should I do to retrieve byte data from such a map?

Comment: I think you should fix the code that is putting a `byte[]` value into the `MappedRecord`.  It is wrong, wrong, wrong!!!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is Java.

While the declaration `HashMap<String, String>` states that the HashMap is expected to be String->String, the static type checking in the compiler is not airtight (given that it's kind of a kluge tacked onto the previously-existing language).

And there is no dynamic type checking to assure that (A) the HashMap you have really is a `HashMap<String, String>`, and (B) someone hasn't inserted an array into a `HashMap<String, String>`.  This is because in reality what you have is a `HashMap<Object, Object>`, so there's no way to implement either dynamic check.